# Weird problem with hyphenation, no MWE unfortunately

Tags: hyphenation, split

I am not sure what's wrong with the .tex file, and I can't generate a MWE, but it seems like my manuscript uses hyphenation (splitting a word across two lines) at weird places.

For example, it split the word without to withou-t and the word or to o-r (!).

There are examples of this sort all across the manuscript, and I am not sure what's causing it. Any idea what controls this?

Comment: The standard configuration doesn't permit such hyphenation. Could you at least paste the preamble of your document (everything before `\begin{document}`)? Or upload the whole document to a pastebin and link it here. It's really hard to help without seeing some code.

Comment: You have set the right hyphen minimum to 1. I can't say how, though.

Comment: you must be able to make a MWE: start from a copy of your document, delete everything after the paragraph with the first bad hyphen, then try deleting everything before that paragraph, checking at each stage that the problem is still there. When you have a complete one-paragraph document with a bad hyphen, post the code here.